# Slow boot process while ubuntu starts because of systemd temporary file creation

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, boot, startup, tmp

I run ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell laptop; I just love the fact that you can set the workspace to a grid format in 16.04, unlike say 18.04 where it looks like a line, but not sure if 20 does have the grid workspace setup. CPU: Intel Core i5-i7 RAM: 8GB Storage: 512GB PCIe SSD.

When i start ubuntu, i get a message:

```
A job is running for creating volatile and temporary files and directories
```

This process takes a while to complete so that ubuntu eventually starts as can be seen in:

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain 
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 25.315s
└─multi-user.target @2min 25.315s
  └─hddtemp.service @2min 25.291s +22ms
    └─network-online.target @2min 25.290s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @2min 15.008s +10.280s
        └─NetworkManager.service @2min 12.427s +2.568s
          └─dbus.service @2min 12.223s
            └─basic.target @2min 12.168s
              └─sockets.target @2min 12.166s
                └─snapd.socket @2min 12.124s +39ms
                  └─sysinit.target @2min 12.103s
                    └─systemd-update-utmp.service @2min 12.063s +38ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @5.904s +2min 6.076s
                        └─local-fs.target @5.897s
                          └─local-fs-pre.target @5.705s
                            └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @4.067s +1.635s
                              └─kmod-static-nodes.service @3.861s +202ms
                                └─systemd-journald.socket @3.485s
                                  └─-.slice @2.994s
```

What could be the reason behind `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` taking up too much time while booting?

Comment: Ok. I own Dell Inspiron with UHD Display, i7-7700hq CPU, 512GB NVMe PCIe SSD, 32GB RAM etc. I believe the 16.04 is not ready for such a setup, by that I mean you should probably move upwards. But I can be mistaken.

Comment: Do you mean the grid workspace view? i've set it up its what i use that's why i'm suck at 16, but will check out 20

Comment: I meant the Ubuntu 16.04 base is terribly old, and thus could lead to some mysterious consequences you described. I think trying out [Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=281) might be a worth a shot, as on my latop it is running like a charm and you have a very similar setup. Cheers in any case.